# How to set heredoc output to local variable

Tags: bash, shell, here-document

I'm trying in a heredoc to set its output to a local variable as follows :

```sh
REMOTE_OUTPUT=$(ssh remote@server /bin/bash << EOF
  find my/path/ -type f -not -path my/path/*/ -type f -mtime -0 | while read filename; do
        if grep "ERROR" $filename; then
            filenamebase=$(basename "$filename")
            echo -e "\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\n$filenamebase failure:\n"
            grep -n "ERROR" "$filename" | sed G
        fi
    done
EOF)
```

But the variable stays null even though the find&grep loop is correct and should indeed return an output.

(Otherwise I would also be interested in writing the output of the heredoc into a local file.)

Comment: What's that mean: "find&grep loop is correct"?    How do you know?

Comment: I mean I have tried it locally to check that the output is not empty (same folders and files in the local and remote servers)

Comment: Did you try with `ssh`, but without the command substitution `REMOTE_OUTPUT=$( )`?

Comment: Yes it works fine but I need to store the output to append it to a file whose content will be sent in a mail

Comment: What happens if you put  ` > somefile`  after the `<< EOF`?

Comment: Nothing is append to the file

Comment: What happens if you run your command with here-doc but without command substitution? Also, have you tried to run `ssh` with `-T` option?

Comment: Did the command go back to the prompt or did you have to interrupt it with control-C?

Comment: Meuh found the solution below :)

Comment: Did you try the `>somefile` without the `$()`?

Comment: Did you delete the `ssh` too?

Comment: Did you try everything in the answer below?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the `EOF` marker, eg `<<\EOF` or `<<'EOF'` to stop
your `$filename` variable from being evaluated before it is passed to the remote.  You can see the effect with say `/bin/bash -v` instead of `/bin/bash`.

I also needed to have the actual `EOF` marker on a line of its own, with the final `)` on the next line.

Comment: I think the problem is the EOF) because questioner said the command worked without the command substitution $().

Comment: I've done it, it is it that solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic example but I was able to accomplish this same thing with interactive nslookup:

```
output_text=`nslookup<<-monkies
      www.google.com
      exit
      monkies`
echo "Output: $output_text"
```

By wrapping the entire command in tildes the output can be stored to a variable. It's not always pretty (depending upon the command being executed by the heredoc) but it does work.

This solved the problem I was having with storing heredoc output to a variable in bash.